# How to do asymptotics for integrals?

Tags: asymptotics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

What's a good way to find how fast the integral of a function is growing near a pole of the function? Here is what I mean on an example.

Look at 1/z. 
If I want to find out how fast ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>a</sup> 1/(z-ε)dz is growing when ε->0, ε∈C, I can do this:

∫<sub>0</sub><sup>a</sup> 1/(z-ε)dz = ln((a-ε)/ε)=-ln(-ε)+ln(a)+ε/a+O(ε).

What if I have ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>a</sup> f(z)/(z-ε) dz , where f(z) is finite?

Comment: My first guess is that you might need something slightly stronger than being differentiable (perhaps bounded variation in some neighbourhood of 0).

Comment: I rephrased the question, so hopefully its more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to see how fast it blows up, it shouldn't be too hard. First integrate by parts:

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f(z)/(z-ε) dz = f(1)log(1-ε) - f(0)log(-ε) - ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)log(z-ε) dz.

For the integral on the right-hand side, note that when you set ε to 0, you get ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)log(z) dz, which should converge (to a finite value) as long as f'(z) is bounded, so let's rewrite the integral as

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)log(z-ε) dz = ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)log(z) dz + 
>   ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)(log(z-ε) - log(z)) dz.

The second integral looks like it should converge to 0 as ε goes to 0. To confirm this, it seems advantageous to deal with the singularity at z=0 first (there may be a cleaner way). Make the change of variables z = u<sup>2</sup>:

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)(log(z-ε) - log(z)) dz = 2∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup>f'(u<sup>2</sup>) u(log(u<sup>2</sup>- ε) - log(u<sup>2</sup>)) du,

and now it shouldn't be too hard to show that the integrand converges uniformly to 0 as ε goes to 0 if f'(z) is bounded. This gives the estimate

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f(z)/(z-ε) dz = -f(0)log(-ε) - ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f'(z)log(z) dz + o(1).

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I had been looking in the wrong direction.